# Laravel how to query on Collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

There is a model in my Laravel app called `HourlyPrice` with columns `['value', 'user_id', 'vehicle_type_id']`;

I need to query on all the records of this model in a blade file. In face many finds are needed, to do so, instead of querying the whole model each time, I pass its collection to the blade file and then trying to query on it as follows

```
$complexes = User::complex()->get();
$vehicle_types = VehicleType::all();
$prices = HourlyPrice::all();
return view('crm::hourly.price', compact('complexes', 'vehicle_types', 'prices'));
```

now to find a specific record I write

```
$prices->where('user_id', 3)->where('vehicle_type_id', 7)->first();
```

The query returns null while

```
HourlyPrice::where('user_id', 3)->where('vehicle_type_id', 7)->first();
```

returns the record. What is wrong here?

To explain more:

```
$prices->where('user_id', 3)->first();
```

returns a record but when I attach the seconds where it returns null.

This is the dd of `prices`

[image]

I showed one record but there are 12 records with value.

thanks

Comment: Would you try `dd`-ing the `$prices` variable and sharing the output in a comment?

Comment: @RaedYakoubi I added that

Comment: I have tried running the code and it works correctly for me, would you re-check if the attribute name in the where clause is `vehicle_type_id` or `vehicule_type_id`, this might be caused by a typo?

Comment: @TsaiKoga i think that is what they actually are trying to achieve

Comment: @TsaiKoga actually it is one record

Comment: @RaedYakoubi I added the relations as Yomna Hesham said and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the `vehicle_type` relationship.

So use the following code:

```
$prices = HourlyPrice::with("vehicle_type")->get() ;
```

Instead of:

```
$prices = HourlyPrice::all();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! it is surprising,  I didn't use any relation but it actually needs that. Why does this work?

Comment: Oh i thought that was hardcoded and not really related.
It would be nice to note in the answer that this is called Eager Loading (https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: @RaedYakoubi no hard code, there are many users and some vehicle types. Every user must be assigned a value which corresponds to a vehicle type

Comment: @MamaD Yes i figured that out after this has worked for you :)

Comment: @MamaD if you don't build the relationship between them, this line will occurs `Call to undefined relationship`error. And collection can works with `where()`, maybe something wrong with other code.

Comment: Check the updated answer ... @RaedYakoubi thanks for your modification